# Django models: default value for column

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have following `Django` model code:

```
status = models.PositiveIntegerField(default = 0b000)
comments_allowed = models.BooleanField(default = True) # whether comments are allowed to this post
```

But I expected, it would generate SQL like

```
`status` integer NOT NULL default '4',
`comments_allowed` bool NOT NULL default TRUE
```

Which is not happening and when I run `manage.py sqlall appname` it produces:

```
`status` integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`comments_allowed` bool NOT NULL
```

Delving into `Django`'s code and googling gave me nothing, but James Bennet's comment that `default` is not assumed to affect generating `SQL`, but needed for Django admin. Even if so, how do I get desired effect?

My `Django` version is 1.3.0 final

Comment: The fact that `default` can also be assigned callable objects would indicate that it is used mainly during model instance creation. Apart from manually running the `SQL ALTER` command, AFAIK it's not possible to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Shawn. I expected this answer 'cause my googling brought no results.

Comment: Relevant ticket : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/470

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that the `default` parameter can also take a callable object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default. That is certainly a behavior that cannot be reproduced in SQL! So it would not be possible for Django to generate SQL for every possible case. It looks like for the sake of simplicity and consistency they have chosen not to generate SQL for any case.

Comment: Well, this is one of the most useful things in SQL - to provide a default value when creating column. Too bad for `Django` :(

Comment: @Nemoden you can always manually change your SQL.  Django added this to make it more flexible.  As with many things in Django and Python, if you don't like it you can change it!

Comment: Sure, yes... But... I'm just disappointed. It's not hard to provide it out from the box, right? :) `If !callable add default value into create column statement`... And it is really confusing, cause as `Django` rookie you think `Ok, good... We have a default option here, so let's provide some default value` and it just does nothing... And first you thought "Wow, Django models are so cool" and now you all "Wheee.... they are not that cool" :) THat's okay, actually. I'm just upset now :)

Answer (score 9):

The only permanent solution is to patch the Django source, specifically db/backends/creation.py:

Find:

```
if f.primary_key:
    field_output.append(style.SQL_KEYWORD('PRIMARY KEY'))
elif f.unique:
    field_output.append(style.SQL_KEYWORD('UNIQUE'))
```

After add:

```
if(f.default != models.fields.NOT_PROVIDED):
    field_output.append(style.SQL_KEYWORD('DEFAULT ' + str(f.default)))
```

(Source: http://www.supermind.org/blog/671/django-not-setting-default-column-value-in-mysql)

Alternatively (and preferably), if you're using [South](https://south.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you can just execute some additional SQL after the `db.create_table` in your migration:

MySQL:

```
db.execute("ALTER TABLE yourapp_yourmodel MODIFY status int Default '4'")
```

Postgres:

```
db.execute("ALTER TABLE yourapp_yourmodel ALTER COLUMN status SET DEFAULT 4")
```

---

Comment: Exactly! Not only I who is upset about this :) Thank you for the solution. I can't accept it though as it is a dirty-dirty-dirty-hack. So for now I'll go with `alter table mytable modify column status bool not null default TRUE`

Comment: Ummm... I said as much in the answer, and also advised that you find an alternate means such as using South to automatically add the column, because it's not a good idea to patch the source. Which seems to be exactly what you plan to do, either via South or manually.

Comment: I'm confused...has anybody submitted a patch to Django?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that django has supported the default parameters in MySQL 8.0.13+.
[Fixed #30712 -- Allowed BLOB/TEXT defaults on MySQL 8.0.13+.](https://github.com/django/django/pull/11679)

Comment: When you create a migration for a `NOT NULL` field it'll prompt you for a "default" to fill existing fields.  That seems to be accomplished by temporarily adding a `DEFAULT` value on the column and then `DROP`ing it afterwards as part of the migration.  I think that's what this is.