# Are NULL and FALSE the same for mysql django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django models: default value for column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153482/django-models-default-value-for-column)

I have created a model field like this in models

```
profile_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
```

Now when I see the database table in mysql dbshell

it is showing me information for profile_complete like this

```
 Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
 profile_complete | tinyint(1)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
```

I have set the `Default` as False for it then why it is showing `NULL` as default for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153482/django-models-default-value-for-column).

When you assign a default value for a model field (which can even be a callable), this value is set by the Django ORM for every object in case another value is not provided while saving.

That means if you will insert some records manually, through the DB shell, this default value won’t be used.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is interpreted as `False` while a set bit is interpreted as `True`.

Comment: Does it behave like NULL also then ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ALTER TABLE profile_complete MODIFY COLUMN profile_complete NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE;
```