# django, CharField default value is ignored in SQL

Tags: django, django-models

I have defined django dummy model as following:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    test = CharField(max_length = 100, default = 'Test!')
```

it results into the following SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `uman_test` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `test` varchar(100) NOT NULL
);
```

but I expect the default value in SQL also:

```
CREATE TABLE `uman_test` (
    `id` integer AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `test` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Test!'
);
```

- python 2.7.3
- django is 1.5.4
- backend MySQL

why does django model creator ignore the default value?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153482/django-models-default-value-for-column

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default value of the field is not in the SQL schema because Django's internals will take care of it - not the database. Before saving the model object, Django will take care to set the default value for this field.

[From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default):
"The default value for the field. This can be a value or a callable object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is created."

You can have a callable (a function) as a default value and this can not be represented in the SQL schema.

Comment: Thank you Lucho! That's great help! :)

Yes, I read the doc (you referred), but I was confused by this 'callable' comment. I thought that if I provide const value, then it should be taken into SQL.